# Python - Function to find last number

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that returns the very last digit in a python string and if there are no digits in the string, it simply returns -5 as a result.
This is what i've gotten but it returns 0 if the string is made up of no digits or if the final character in the string is not a digit.
For example, `LastNum("1*2*3*")` should return `3`, `LastNum("****")` should return `-5`. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
def LastNum(st):
    Result = 0
    for i in (st):
        if i.isdigit():
            Result = Result + int(max(st[-1::]))
    return Result
```

Comment: Shouldn't `LastNum("****")` return `-5`?

Comment: My apologies, typo. It should be -5.

Answer (score 3):

It would be a good idea to start searching from the reverse

```
def lastNum(st):
    # st[::-1] is reverse of st
    for s in st[::-1]:
        if s.isdigit():
            return int(s)

    return -5
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the intended logic behind your code, but this simpler one should work:

```
def LastNum(st):
    Result = -5
    for i in st:
        if i.isdigit():
            Result = int(i)
    return Result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex as follows too.

```
import re

def LastNum(st):
    result = -5
    regex_res = re.findall('\d+', st)
    if regex_res:
        result = regex_res[-1]
    return result

print LastNum("1*2*3*")
```

**output:**

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice one-liner (probably not the most readable way to do it though)

```
import re

def LastNum(st, default=-5):
    return int((re.findall(r'\d', st) or [default])[-1])
```